# What to extend for a new custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Some people suggest to just extend `Panel` but I also know about `UserControl` that sounds like something I should extend to make my own control.

**`Panel`** vs. **`UserControl`** vs. **`Control`** vs. **`another_alternative`**

```
// inheritance depth:
Control
Panel : ScrollableControl : Control
UserControl : ContainerControl : ScrollableControl : Control
```

All I need is a rectangle to draw and full WinApi ability (Handle, WndProc etc.). But I want to avoid all the extras that might come into the play. I want to use my custom controls to add them to standard forms. No extreme actions.

On the other hand UserControl extends ContainerControl that might have functionality I want (I'm not sure).

---

I inherited from `Control` for an OpenGL box and some other simple controls. They work fine so far. I haven't noticed any functionality-loss. **Does something speak against `Control` ?** *(in case I don't require any extra functionality)*

Comment: use the user control, and please check before you publish a question, the is so much information in google and examples even in youtube so you can see what you can get

Comment: Why is inheritance depth important?

Comment: @joe It's just an FYI thing.

Comment: For WinAPI, won't you need to handle everything at the *window* level? You just need an element that supports keyboard focus (which is *any* `UIElement`), and set up a WndProc for the host window that does `if (Keyboard.FocusedElement == yourElement) ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the unofficial and accepted "standard" is to just inherit from `UserControl`. At least that's what I've seen everywhere else. *That does not make it the right thing though!*

On the other hand, I think you also may be too concerned about the "right thing" to do here. To me, this is almost similar to *premature optimization*. You want to make sure that you spend your resources wisely.

Also keep in mind that things like this can always be changed later.

If you're concerned for a reason, I would definitely pick the **simplest** of the controls with the **lowest** inheritance depth.

Comment: @mini-me - then go for `Panel`. Follow your developer-heart.

Comment: My heart goes for `Control` because it's the ***simplest** and of **lowest** inheritance depth*.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly `UserControl` is the best class to inherit from. Another option could be to inherit from the class that we want to customize.

In your case, `Panel` should be the best class to inherit from as it is the simplest control class that would serve your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`Panel` would be ideal here because you are not defining a layout for the control. Nor does it need a `ControlTemplate`. Custom rendering schemes generally come with the recommendation to use `Panel`. While `Control` is the simplest 'layout' element you can get at, `Panel` has the ability to host child controls should you need to later. Perfect!

Comment: Um, control can host controls already. Buttons can host GridBoxes and all kinds of crazy stuff.

Comment: Buttons inherit from ContentControl, not directly from control. This allows them to host a single piece of child content (any object). Panels are capable of hosting many elements (including content controls) right out of the box. The only thing the inheritor needs to define is the layout method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx

Comment: a) This looks like an error in MSDN to me. Because judging by the metadata of .NET Framework Button does **not** inherit from any ContentControl. b) A Control (buttons too) can host (have child controls) as many other controls as you want.

Comment: @mini-me I don't know what metadata you're looking at, but `typeof(ContentControl).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Button))` is true, so Button definitely inherits ContentControl. However you're right that all controls can host other controls, because they use ControlTemplates. The difference between "content" and simply nesting controls is the use of a [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx), which translates data to elements through DataTemplates. For instance, when you set Content to a string, the presenter will generate a TextBlock.

Comment: When I said a ContentControl can only host a single child I meant a single _direct_ child.

Answer (score 0):

There is a description of what exactly differentiates `UserControl` from `ContentControl` in the "Pro WPF" book, which gives more information than MSDN. Here is a direct link to the section:

http://books.google.ca/books?id=znAVMHNSen0C&pg=PA518&lpg=PA518&dq=%22taking+a+closer+look+at+user+controls%22&source=bl&ots=DjZT-9JCQd&sig=R4MoAzW72PaHvqgZjxPnkkJRs6c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OdQIUrPgDeTYyAGl6oHYAQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22taking%20a%20closer%20look%20at%20user%20controls%22&f=false

The most interesting difference is how it handles routed events. All events raised by contained elements have their [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.source.aspx) reset to the UserControl itself.

I think the conceptual difference is that a ContentControl "contains" its content, while a UserControl's content is "part of" the UserControl. Thus a ContentControl is a distinct element (is focusable / a tab stop) whose contents are handled separately; and setting the content of a UserControl is part of its design process, whose elements are handled directly in the UserControl's code-behind.

So, *my* rules are:

- If the user is meant to inherit it and handle content in code-behind, inherit `UserControl`.
- If it's meant to be used as-is and given arbitrary content, inherit `ContentControl`.
- If it defines its own content, and doesn't have a placeholder for arbitrary content, inherit `Control` and set its [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx).

---

If you just want a rendering surface, I don't think you would need a `Control`. You can use an `ImageSource` for this, like [InteropBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.interopbitmap.aspx) or [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx), which can be attached to an [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush.aspx). For example, it could be used in a stand-alone rectangle:

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush>
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <!-- ImageSource here -->
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
<Rectangle>
```

Or anywhere else that accepts a `Brush`, including the `Background` of another control.

Comment: Ok, I just want to tell that this is not my world. I don't see how you write your C# applications. I use `.NET Framework 4.0` and `ContentControl` is not importable into a fresh WinForms app. I don't know what extra stuff you're using. I would avoid at all costs to code myself into a corner where people wont understand me.

Comment: Well then, it's no wonder you don't know what Gusdor and I are talking about. [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms754130.aspx) also has classes called `Panel`, `UserControl`, and `Control`, it's been part of .NET since 3.0, and it has over 3 times as many followers on stackoverflow than winforms. Be sure to tag your questions with `winforms` to avoid confusion.